Does iOS support multi-process apps like Android does?
I am a long time Android developer with no experience on iOS. I made an Android App that utilizes Android's ability to launch child processes. To be specific, I am leveraging the Proccess tag in Android manifest.
This is a important dependency because we are using many vendor SDKs and we want to give all of them their own sandbox. It's important that each vendor SDK thinks that they are the only one running. We communicate that back up to the host process with remote procedure calls in Android.
Recently I was asked to start to think about how much time it would take to port this to iOS and start hiring some iOS devs. From what I can tell from surface level research, iOS does not support multi-process apps.
Is that true? Is there anything analogous?

No, ios does not have multiple process in the way you described
